# Android build system: How to include prebuilt files from a .tar file?

Tags: android, makefile, build, tar, android-source

I'm building a customized Android system (JellyBean).

**I've got a project (from the upstream) containing a .tar file which should be untar'd at the build time and it's content should be copied to a certain place in the resulting directory tree.
How should I build the makefiles to do it?**

I've tried the following:

1) Writing Android.mk (in the git with the tar) with un-tar instruction and using "PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += ..."

This doesn't work, because PRODUCT_COPY_FILES cannot be used in the Android.mk

2) Writing  Android.mk with untar instructions and some product definition mk file included from AndroidProducts.mk, containing "PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += ..."

This doesn't work, because untar happens AFTER "PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += (ls /untared/dir/*)" and thus PRODUCT_COPY_FILES results empty.

3) Writing product definition mk file doing untar and then "PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += ..."

This works but not so good, because the build system includes this file in multiple places and the untar happens many times(~10) which slows down the build and is not nice ...

Comment: How about `definition.mk` calling `android.mk` recursively? Or if `android.mk` must be the master makefile, have it untar, then call `secondary.mk` (which will do `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` and then all the real work) recursively?

Comment: Mmm, could you elaborate ? I believe , I haven't understood ... What you mean under "definition.mk"? And "recursively" - does it mean that something calls it self? And how do you "call" ?

Comment: I'll answer, but there might be an easier way. Do you have control over the *initial* assignment to `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES`?

Comment: Mmm. What you mean the initial assignment ? The place where which does '=' and not '+=' ? Let's say, I have all the sources but they come from an upstream, and I should minimize the number of gits I change ...

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Is it `=` or `:=`?

Comment: Well it's defined with "assign now", I mean ':=' in the build/core/product_config.mk (part of Android build system) as following 
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES := \
    $(strip $(PRODUCTS.$(INTERNAL_PRODUCT).PRODUCT_COPY_FILES))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may take a few iterations.

To restate the problem:

There is an assignment to a variable, and a rule that creates files (by unpacking a tar file). We don't know beforehand what the names of those files will be, but we want them in the variable. Assignments to (and modifications of) variables tend to happen outside rules, so they will be executed before the rules.

Here are a couple of approaches. (It is difficult to know which is best, without greater knowledge of your system.)

**1) Change the initial assignment** from

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES := ...
```

to

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES = ...
```

There are [two types of variable in Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors): *simply* expanded variables and *recursively* expanded variables. (This has nothing to do calling a makefile recursively.) The choice is determined by assigning with `=` or `:=`. If you have a simply expanded variable like

```
LIST := $(shell ls foo/)
```

Then it will contain a list of whatever files are in `foo/` *at the time of assignment*. If you execute a rule that puts files in `foo/`, then another rule that uses `$(LIST)`, the second rule will see only the original file names. But if you use a *recursively* expanded variable:

```
LIST = $(shell ls foo/)
```

then it will contain `$(shell ls foo/)`. This will not be expanded (evaluated) until the variable is used, so the second rule will see all the file names.

If you change `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` to a recursively expanded variable, you can use

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += $(shell ls /untared/dir/*)
```

and the `ls` command will not execute until the variable is used.

**2) Use tar -t**

The `tar` utility allows you to obtain a list of the contents of a tar file without actually unpacking it.

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += $(shell tar -tf tarfile)
```

(You may have to use some filtering or other path-manipulation to get what you want.)

**3) Use Make recursively**

[Recursive use of Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion) is when Make executes Make, with either the same makefile or a different one.

Maybe `definition.mk` unpacks the tar file, then calls `android.mk`:

```
# definition.mk

all:
    tar -xvf ...
    $(MAKE) -f android.mk
```

When `android.mk` begins, the files are already present in `/untared/dir/`.

Or if you want `android.mk` to be the master makefile that calls other makefiles, you could simply swap the names.